# Animating twitter bootstrap 3 responsive class change

Tags: jquery-ui, animation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page I've set up using twitter bootstrap, I have a layout like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="col-1" class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div id="col-2" class="col-xs-8"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and what I'd like to do is animate a change in width.  What I had originally tried to do was animate a class change with jquery ui like so:

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    $("#col-1").switchClass("col-xs-4", "col-xs-1", 300);
    $("#col-1").switchClass("col-xs-8", "col-xs-12", 300);
});
```

but this didn't work, any idea on how do to do this?

Comment: yea, using jquery ui here

Answer (score 2):

Reply to

> is it possible to make it animate to col-xs-0 –  loriensleafs Dec 18
>   '13 at 15:01

Instead of creating a col-xs-0 and changing the class as beneath as suggested by Bass Jobsen

```js
$("#col-1").switchClass("col-xs-8", "col-xs-0", 300);
```

You could just do the following

```js
$("#col-1").hide(300);
```

Both will work but it's cleaner this way

Answer (score 0):

I don't find a reason why your code shouldn't work, see also: http://bootply.com/101242

In your code you use `$("#col-1").switchClass("col-xs-8", "col-xs-12", 300);` this has `col-1` in stead of col-2 as selector. `col-1` doesn't have a `col-xs-8` class, so can't switch this.

Comment: is it possible to make it animate to col-xs-0

Comment: There won't be a definition of `.col-xs-0` in bootstrap. If there was it should mean something like 0% so hidden. I think you could define in in your css: `.col-xs-0{width:0%;}`